# clipPath circle not inheriting the correct position in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, cross-browser, clip-path

I'm using a circular clip path for my nodes (in d3.js) as follows:

```
<g class="node" id="140" transform="translate(392.3261241288836,64.3699106556645)">

  <image class="mainImage" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="images/manual-story-140.jpg" width="100" height="116.66705555685185" x="-50" y="-50" clip-path="url(#140)">
  </image>

  <clipPath class="clipPath" id="140">
    <circle class="clipPathCircle" stroke-width="1" r="42"></circle>
  </clipPath>

  <circle class="outlinecircle" stroke="#0099FF" fill="url(#myLinearGradient1)" stroke-width="3" r="42"></circle>

</g>
```

But in Firefox the images don't load because the circle element within the clipPath element doesn't inherit the position of the node (i.e. from the g element).

In Chrome/Safari, everything works great and when I open up the console and hover over the circle element that's within the clipPath element it clearly shows the circle in the correct place (with dimensions of 84x84 since the radius is 42).

But in Firefox I see no images, and when I hover over the circle using the console I see it's positioned at the top left of the screen with dimensions 0x0.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?  Do I have to give an absolute position of the circle for firefox or should it already understand from the g-element it's in?

Comment: sorry to chase on this but does anyone have any thoughts?  Even a general approach to help troubleshoot further?  Thanks!

Comment: just found something relevant on this here: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/ - the comment from AmeliaBR suggests the issue might be fixed using an attribute of clipPathUnits with a value of objectBoundingBox within the clipPath element.  Unfortunately that not only doesn't fix the firefox problem, but breaks the clipPath on other browsers (so that I get square images applied).  Really out of options on this now so any thoughts at all would be hugely appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Did you change the coordinate/size values to be appropriate for objectBoundingBox units?

Comment: Sorry Robert, but based on the code I posted, what element/attributes do you think I need to do that to?  I notice from Amelia's comment that "a length of 1 is treated as a length of 100%" but struggling to translate that into a change required to my existing code?  Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks Robert, but I'm not using percentages with those attributes so what unit do I convert into?  In case the numbers alone were being interpreted as units I added "px" to the end of both but have the same problem (works great in Chrome/Safari, not in Firefox)

Comment: make the numbers smaller by the conversion factor. You're not adding unit types.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91494/discussion-between-d3wannabe-and-robert-longson).

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the false alarm, but the problem here (as you can see in my original code) was that I was using the same id on my parent g element as I was to reference my clipPath!  I changed the "id" attribute for my clip path to start with the string "clipPath-" and now it works on Firefox.  Not sure why that would affect different browsers differently (which is why I kinda went 'round the houses trying to troubleshoot the bug), but thankfully enough it's quite a trivial fix!